# What is an Odd Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

If a word has a certain property, I call it an Odd Word™.

In each of the short, unrelated sentences below, only one of the choices is an Odd Word™.

The sentences are for context only, and do not affect whether a word is an Odd Word™. Since a change in case or font might change the property, I have used all upper case, and made sure that the property holds true in the display font.

> 1. SHE'S LEARNING TO MAKE (**FEATHERSTITCHES / WHIPSTITCHES**) TODAY.
> 2. HE LOVES TO RIDE HIS NEW (**BICYCLE / MOTORCYCLE**).
> 3. NOBODY WANTS TO BE KNOWN AS (**AVERAGE / ORDINARY**).
> 4. JESSICA RAN THE RACE (**QUICKLY / RAPIDLY**).
> 5. HE WANTED HER TO (**ANSWER / RESPOND**) BY NOON.
> 6. GIVE (**HER / HIM**) ALL YOUR REP POINTS.
> 7. THE CHILD HID (**BESIDE / UNDER**) THE TABLE.
> 8. THEY ATE (**BECAUSE / WHILE**) THEY HAD THE TIME.
> 9. (**GOODNESS / YIKES**), LOOK AT ALL THE PEOPLE!
> 10. THE DOG (**CHEWED / GNAWED**) ON A BONE.

**What makes a word an Odd Word™?**

Comment: I was going to say that something was an odd word iff it had an odd number of letters, but then QUICKLY/RAPIDLY and CHEWED/GNAWED put that down.

Comment: @JoeZ. Come on, Joe! I'm rooting for you on this one. I'm kinda surprised you haven't gotten one of these Phrase™ or Word™ puzzles already, being the lightning fast solver that you are. Of course, I remember you *were* crazy close on the Scalable Phrase™ puzzle.

Comment: It's more a function of I haven't really been on the website much lately. Working on too much stuff and it's distracting.

Comment: @JoeZ. Well, I'm sure others are glad to have that extra time to think!

Comment: Remember how I complained I never get these? I might've got this one if I hadn't been so late getting here

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but what's to say it's not just, say, the first word of each pair by virtue of being the first?

Comment: @warspyking I know! I wish I could somehow announce when I will post these, so everyone has fair warning.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An Odd Word™ is one that...

> has an odd number of "ends". An 'end' is a place where a letter in the word meets blank space in all but one direction; that is, if you were walking on the letter there would be only one way to go. For instance, RESPOND has 10 ends: two on the bottom of the R, three on the right of the E, two on the S, one on the P, and two on the N.
>  **FEATHERSTITCHES**: 41 (WHIPSTITCHES: 30)
>  **MOTORCYCLE**: 19 (BICYCLE: 14)
>  **ORDINARY**: 13 (AVERAGE: 16)
>  **QUICKLY**: 17 (RAPIDLY: 12)
>  **ANSWER**: 13 (RESPOND: 10)
>  **HER**: 9 (HIM: 8)
>  **UNDER**: 9 (BESIDE: 10)
>  **WHILE**: 13 (BECAUSE: 14)
>  **GOODNESS**: 11 (YIKES: 14)
>  **GNAWED**: 11 (CHEWED: 14)

I'll take my 100 rep now. ;)

Comment: Deusovi, that was quick! Nice answer, and congratulations on being the first to get more than one of these types of my puzzles. Your 100 bonus rep will be awarded in a week or less!

Comment: @JLee: Thanks! :D Great puzzle as usual.

Comment: Man, I was too slow double checking my answer. Well done.

Comment: @Eli: I double-checked mine too. I guess I just got here slightly faster.

Comment: \*sigh\* You even hinted at the appearance of the letters and I kept trying to make the letters themselves work regardless of appearance...

Comment: @JoeZ. Well, you can't solve them all! I have no doubt that one of these will go to you eventually.

Comment: Doesn't RESPOND have 10 ends (rather than 8)? 2+3+2+1+2=10

Comment: @psmears Welp, I can't count. Fixed.

Comment: How do people think of these things?

Answer (score 9):

An odd word is a word that

> has the odd number of 'endpoints'. For example, the letter A has 2 endpoints at the bottom; B has 0 because it is closed. C has 2; D has 0, E has 3, etc.
>  This will only works for the displayed font and case.
> 1.FEATHERSTITCHES = 41 total endpoints
> 2.MOTORCYCLE = 19
> 3.ORDINARY = 13
> 4.QUICKLY = 15
> 5.ANSWER = 13
> 6.HER = 9
> 7.UNDER = 9
> 8.WHILE = 13
> 9.GOODNESS = 11
> 10.GNAWED = 11