# What Am I Talking About?

Tags: riddle, word

I hope you enjoy puzzling out the following:

> Free three months
>   Jump the flower.
>   Originate the coil.
>   Reverse the addendum and finish with a bell sound.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're talking about

> SPRING.

Free three months

> The are three months in the season of spring; "spring" can also mean to free

Jump the flower.

> Jumping is "springing", and flowers appear in spring; also, a spring, the body of water, is a "flow-er".

Originate the coil.

> Both "originate" and "coil" are synonyms of "spring".

Reverse the addendum and finish with a bell sound.

> P.S. is an addendum; a bell sound is a RING. Reverse and concatenate to get SPRING.

Comment: Bro, I can not even type, how is that fair :( !

Comment: Spring can be another word for free as well, as in freeing someone from the prison of winter (ooooh, metaphor).

Comment: In the second part of the second line, ask yourself how you might describe a thing which proceeds as one form of this thing does. As another comment points out, the first word is a clue on its own. Thus, three double clues followed by a two-part single clue. Couldn't stop myself once I got going.

Comment: @riddler: I have a [bit](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25577/a-rhyming-six-words-puzzle) of a [reputation](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19857/what-is-an-odd-word/19858#19858) for [quick answers](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19916/what-is-an-uncopyrightable-word/19918#19918).